# Simplest way to send money in a PayPal account using the credit card, without any accounts

Tags: online-payment

Is there any *simple* web application that can be used to send money from credit card to somebody else PayPal account without creating an account?

So, no account should be required to *send* money. The sender should provide the card information and the receiver PayPal email address and the receiver will receive the money on PayPal.

In my case, the payer who sends the money is in USA and the receiver is in Romania.

Is there such a thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is called PayPal - anybody with a PayPal account can receive money from anybody - the **payer** can either have a PayPal account themselves **or** can pay PayPal with a Credit/Debit card.  If they use a credit card or there are currency conversions &/or cross border transactions then there are some fees to the payee.

If you log in to your PayPal account and go to [paypalme](https://www.paypal.com/paypalme) you will get a link to send them that they can click on, they will then need to enter the amount and select the payment method.

Comment: Good to know but paypalme is not supported in my country (Romania)... :(

Comment: It might be worth adding the location issue to your question as due to banking regulations, and other issues, solutions might well be specific to a given location - also is the person providing the funds in the same country as that can raise some issues.